# Legenda gráfico de barras

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como é possível inserir uma legenda no gráfico abaixo distinguindo as barras em cores diferentes?

Segue o comando utilzado:

```
names(medias)=c("1","2","3","4")
barra=barplot(medias,xlab="x",ylab="y",ylim=c(0,25))
text(0.7,18.3+0.0061+0.1,"15.5")
text(1.9,17+0.0061+0.1,"14.5")
text(3.1,17+0.0061+0.1,"14.5 ")
text(4.25,15+0.0061+0.1,"12.25")
```

[image: gráfico]

Comment: `?barplot` vai te ajudar a responder essas perguntas.

Answer (score 3):

Pode criar um vetor com as cores desejadas e indica-lo para `plot` e `legend`:

```
# Dados de exemplo
medias <- setNames(1:3, 1:3)

cores <- c("blue", "green", "red")

barplot(medias, col = cores)
legend("top", horiz = TRUE, legend = names(medias), fill = cores)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho a certeza se o código seguinte responde à pergunta mas põe os valores das médias em cima de barras todas de cores diferentes.

```r
medias <- c(15.5, 14.5, 14.5, 12.25)

names(medias) <- c("1","2","3","4")
cores <- rainbow(length(medias))
barra <- barplot(medias, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", ylim = c(0, 25), col = cores)
text(barra, medias, labels = medias, adj = c(0.5, -1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>